# Number of nodes in a BST which are bigger than a given KEY

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I wrote the code bellow to **count** number of nodes in a BST which are bigger than a given KEY:

```
int Tree::findNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(int key){
    return PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key, this->rootNode);
}

int Tree::PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(int key, Node* start) {
    if (!start)
        return 0;

    if (start->key > key)
        return 1 + this->PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key, start->leftNode) +
        this->PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key, start->rightNode);

    else if (start->key < key)
        return this->PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key, start->rightNode);

    else /*start->key > key*/
        return this->PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key, start->leftNode);
}
```

this is my main:

```
int main() {

    int TreeKeys[16] = { 50, 76, 21, 4, 32, 64, 15, 52, 14, 100, 83, 2, 3, 70, 87, 80 };
    Tree myBst;

    cout << "Printing the three Inorder before adding numbers: \n";
    myBst.printInorder();


    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        myBst.AddLeaf(TreeKeys[i]);
    }

    cout << "Printing the three Inorder after adding numbers: \n";
    myBst.printInorder();

    int key = 2;
    cout << "\n\nNumber of nodes that are bigger than "<<key<<" : " <<
         myBst.findNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key);
    return 0;
}
```

The Inroder print works just fine:

```
Printing the three Inorder after adding numbers:
2 3 4 14 15 21 32 50 52 64 70 76 80 83 87 100
```

but when I serach for number of nodes that are bigger than "2" I get 14 which is incorrect (instead of 15):

```
Number of nodes that are bigger than 2 : 14
```

When I search for number of nodes that are bigger than "1" I get 16 which is correct result (I get a correct result for any other numbers too):

```
Number of nodes that are bigger than 1 : 16
```

I'm a student and newbie with recursion, I'll be glad for explanations why that's happened and how can I fix it.

Comment: Indent your code. And provide an MCVE.

Comment: Good news! This is an excellent opportuntity for you to learn how to use your debugger, which will allow you to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables on each step, and observe your program's logical flow.  Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Nobody gets an exception from this requirement. Once you learn how to use your debugger you will be able to debug, find, and fix these kinds of bugs in your own code without running to stackoverflow.com and hoping someone else could do it for you.

Comment: Less arbitrary, and smaller, test data makes it much easier to find problems.

Comment: @BenjaminYakobi "_done!_" This isn't [mcve]. Can we copy-paste the code, that you provided, to reproduce the issue?

Comment: No, you're wrong. You're not "done". Your shown code still fails to meet all requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. Unless anyone can cut-n-paste what you've showed, compile, run, and reproduce your problem, it obviously fails the "Complete" requirement.

Comment: "AddLeaf" is a strange name for a function that doesn't add a leaf.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have debugged it before I came to stackoverflow. if I'm asking here, it's only because I didn't find whats the problem. Sorry that I didn't mention that. I truley didn't understand why thats happend.

I can't copy-paste my whole Homework (more than 400+) lines. I show the problematic function. It's meaningless to copy-paste evreything.

If you can help, I'll truley be glad and thank you for that. and if not its ok too but I dont have any other way right now to describe my question.

Comment: @BenjaminYakobi 1) "_I can't copy-paste my whole Homework (more than 400+) lines. I show the problematic function. It's meaningless to copy-paste evreything._" No one has asked you to copy-paste everything. We asked you to produce [mcve] (did you read the link for details?). 2) "_I show the problematic function._" You would be amazed at the amount of times, we see people providing "only relevant function" only to find the issue in the code outside of such relevant function. (not saying that this is the case here, but that's one of the reasons for [mcve] requirement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `else` is not correct, it's condition is `start->key == key` which should be treated the same as `start->key < key`

so rewrite it to

```
else 
   return this->PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(key, start->rightNode);
```

or simply combine it with `start->key < key`

Comment: Thanks, works fine now. sorry for not providing MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide an MCVE, I cannot work on your code. The general way of doing this, is like that:

```
int Tree::PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(int key, Node* node)
{
  if (node == null)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  int countLeft = PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(node->leftNode, key);
  int countRight = PrivateFindNumbersThatBiggerThanKey(node->rightNode, key);

  return (node->key > k ? 1 : 0) + countLeft + countRight;
}
```